# Connect Topbraid Composer to Stardog with Sesame

Tags: rdf, sparql, sesame, stardog, topbraid-composer

I'm failing to connect Topbraid Composer 4.6.3 to Stardog 3.0 with the help of a Sesame 2.8.1 repository. These are the steps I'm following:

1. Create a new RDF/OWL Sesame2 Repository Connection
2. Entered a File name, Base URI and Service URL. The available repositories are correctly shown.

[image]

3. Select the Stardog repository
4. When I try to connect, the following message is shown

[image]

Also worth mentioning, is the fact that security is enabled in Stardog. Therefore I've added the credentials (http;//admin:admin@url) in the SPARQL query endpoint URL in the Sesame Workbench. There's no security configured for Sesame.

I'm wondering which tool will be the bottleneck. Has anyone done something similar yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stardog does not support the Sesame HTTP API.  If there is a way to connect TopBraid to a database via the SPARQL protocol, I suggest using that option.